# No internet Connection "error" on Android to avoid force quit

Tags: android, json

I'm developing an application with Internet permission.

In the case when I have no internet on the smartphone the application has to quit, this is bothering me.

I tried to use this : but it doesn't work properly !

```
private boolean isNetworkConnected() {
ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) 
        getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
NetworkInfo ni = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
if (ni == null) {
    // There are no active networks.
    return false;
} else
    return true;
}

if (isNetworkConnected()==false) {
    new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
    .setTitle("Problème")
    .setMessage("Vérifiez si vous etes connecté à Internet pour pourvoir utiliser cette application")
    .setPositiveButton("Quitter", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { 
            finish();
            System.exit(0);
        }
     })

    .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
     .show();


}
```

So it there is someone who can suggest anything better, I'm using both of json connection, so for example if the user loses internet in the middle of downloading what kind of code we should use, here is an example of my json class :

```
class RequestTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... uri) {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpResponse response;
        String responseString = null;
        try {
            response = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet(uri[0]));
            StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
            if(statusLine.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK){
                ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                response.getEntity().writeTo(out);
                responseString = out.toString();
                out.close();
            } else{
                //Closes the connection.
                response.getEntity().getContent().close();
                throw new IOException(statusLine.getReasonPhrase());
            }
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            //TODO Handle problems..
        } catch (IOException e) {
            //TODO Handle problems..
        }
        return responseString;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

    }
}
```

If there is any tutorial or any ideas, that would be really helpful.

Comment: where r u getting error...show me your logcat...

Comment: have you added permission in the manifest file?

Comment: use downloadmanger for downloading files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have this method to check the network availability:

```
private boolean networkStatus;
private void checkNetworkAvailable() {
    networkStatus = false;
    try{
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getNetworkInfo(0);
        if (netInfo != null && netInfo.getState()==NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
            networkStatus = true;
        }else {
            netInfo = cm.getNetworkInfo(1);
            if(netInfo!=null && netInfo.getState()==NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED)
                networkStatus = true;
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();  
        networkStatus = false;
    }
}
```

To get the information about the connectivity or availability of the network:

```
if (networkStatus==true) { // if network is available
    // do something
}else{ // if network is not available
    // do something
}
```

Finally, add these permissions in the manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
if (!isNetworkConnected()) {
    new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
    .setTitle("Problème")
    .setMessage("Vérifiez si vous etes connecté à Internet pour pourvoir utiliser cette application")
    .setPositiveButton("Quitter", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { 
            finish();

        }
     })

    .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
     .show();


}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this code to check network connection

```
ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) ctx
                .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        if ((connectivityManager
                .getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE) != null && connectivityManager
                .getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED)
                || (connectivityManager
                        .getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI) != null && connectivityManager
                        .getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI)
                        .getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED)) {
            //put your code here 
        } else {
            // exit your app here
        }
```